# How do I install a ionic plugin from the github repository?

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, ionic3, package.json, ionic-native

The [npm install docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) explains how to install a dependency from the github source code rather than using the npm registry.

It works well when your project isn't scoped, so that if I wanna install express I can just execute:

```
npm install https://github.com/expressjs/express
```

and it works well.

In the ionic plugin case, though, this doesn't work correctly.
Ionic plugins are scoped, if I want to install the speech recognition plugin from the npm registry I can just execute:

```
npm install @ionic-native/speech-recognition
```

[This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/speech-recognition) is the *@ionic-native/speech-recognition* npm page.

On the right sidebar there's the link to the corresponding github page, which is https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native.

If I try to execute:

```
 npm i https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/speech-recognition
```

It installs only the `@ionic-native` dependency rather than the plugin.

The same about:

```
 npm i @ionic-native/speech-recognition@https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native
```

In both cases, the output is:

> @ionic-native/speech-recognition@https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native
> npm WARN @ionic-native/ionic-webview@5.28.0 requires a peer of
> @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer
> dependencies yourself. npm WARN uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 requires
> a peer of webpack@^1.9 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc || ^3.0.0 but
> none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> - ionic-native@5.28.0 updated 1 package and audited 1602 packages in 38.072s

Which only adds the following row in the *package.json*:

> "ionic-native": "git+https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native.git"

If you are asking why I need it, it's because I need to install a forked repo.

How can I install a ionic plugin from the github repository?

Thank you

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to add the Ionic Native wrapper alongwith the cordova plugin, just that the plugin is a fork ?

Answer (score -1):

Most of the plugins used by the **Ionic Framework** where created for **Cordova/Phonegap** way before Ionic was published. These are the main technologies that Ionic was built uppon, so you can find the information where and how to download the plugins from the **Cordova** and **Phonegap** Github pages or official website.
[Speech Recognition for Cordova](https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-speechrecognition)

Comment: The ionic/cordova was just an example, my question is about installing a scoped dependency